# What does number in "more (n)" represent in the footer sites?

Tags: discussion, design, footer

In the footer we have given links to many Stack Exchange Network sites categorized by the type. Each one of them have **more (n)** at the bottom of their listed links. For example; here is a screenshot of the "SCIENCE" section:

> [image]

Upon clicking on "[more (7)](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science)" link, I see there are total 17 sites under the "Science" header. Ditto goes with other footer sites. For a moment, I thought "more (7)" means there are "7 more sites" apart from the 5 listed above under the Science section. But, then that's not true either because it will add up to total 12 sites (5 listed + 7 more). So, the count does not match to the actual sites they have in there. But the system does have a algorithm to calculate and display the *more (number)* for these footer sites.

What does the number in "more (7)" refers to? How should one interpret it?

**P.S.**

Please note, my screenshot does not match to the current "SCIENCE" footer as Oded (♦ moderator) purged the global cache (source (comment): @ShadowWizard - nope, just expired a global, long living cache).

Comment: Are that only the non-beta sites maybe? There seem to be 7 in total in Science.

Comment: @PatrickHofman how do you tell which one is beta and not?

Comment: The icon in front. The 'unstyled' were traditionally the betas.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I am counting the icons on others... Can you tell how  "Life/Arts" got (10)

Comment: See the answer below. Public betas do count too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman refresh the page and see the footer sites and its more count. It's updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means, 7 more sites exist in the "Science" category.

These would all be sites in public beta, hence are not showing up with their name.

Comment: This is a little confusing. Can the UI be updated so it is a little more meaningful?

Comment: What's your suggestion?

Comment: Hey, now I am doing your job ;). Don't know actually. Remove the number, change the number to match the total, or update the label so we know what 7 to expect.

Comment: Maybe a tooltip saying what Oded just wrote, @Pat? Adding more text would be too noisy IMO

Comment: @Oded I'm little confused as for the "Life/Arts" (10) count goes... do I count icons on the front? It comes to 8

Comment: I don't follow, @HackerKarma - "more", as in "additional". As in, more than the ones shown.

Comment: @Oded maybe replace "more" with "all"?

Comment: @PatrickHofman then it would read "all (7)", "all (10)" ... I hope not as that would confuse more. Did you mean to say just "all"?

Comment: @Oded just noticed... the footer sites links "more" counter got updated. now it says "more (5)"

Comment: @Oded did you just add Biology and Chemistry manually now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - nope, just expired a global, long living cache.

Comment: two months cache?? *shudder*

Comment: @Oded changed the title and accepting your answer. One suggestion, may be we can say "see all..." at the bottom instead of "more (n)"

Comment: @ShadowWizard At least 6 months. Expression Engine graduated 2015-01-14 and wasn't in the footer until now.

Comment: Oddly, this didn't make [networkengineering.se] show up in the footer. Or [pt.so], which is also a graduated site now.